# NSManagedObject hasChanges always return false

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a log NSManagedObject, no matter if this is a new object or already saved object with or without changes, the following code will always return triple NO. What might be my problem? Thanks.

```
#define NSStringFromBOOL(aBOOL)    aBOOL? @"YES" : @"NO"
NSLog(@"updated: %@, inserted: %@, hasChanges: %@",
      NSStringFromBOOL([[self log] isUpdated]), 
      NSStringFromBOOL([[self log] isInserted]),
      NSStringFromBOOL([[self log] hasChanges])
      );
```

Comment: What if you save first, change and then check the return values?

Comment: Same, I tried that too. But even if this is a saved object and I'm just modifying it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using UIManagedDocument or do you setup your managed object context with persistent store the old way?

Comment: The old way I guess. I'm not familiar with UIManagedDocument. I am using a persistent store. I have a singleton LogStore using one context cross the app. Thanks...